# Showing and hiding something with pure CSS with show and hide button

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

This is supposed to be pretty simple and straight forward, but I can't seem to get it right and what I am trying to do is pretty specific.

With pure CSS I want to hide a panel by clicking on the 'hide' button, then I want to show it by clicking on the 'show' button.
Thing is, when I click on the hide button, said button hides as well and 'show' button appears. Then when I click the show button, show button will disappear and the hide button will appear in it's place.

As it is now, the 'hide' button does not hide and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Here is the [code with example HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/39u0gamk/2/)

CSS:

```
.panel .hideButton {
  display: block;
}

.showButton{
  display: none;
}

.hide:focus ~ .panel{
  display: none;
}
.hide:focus ~ .hideButton {
  display: none;
}
.hide:focus ~ .showButton {
  display: block;
}

.show:focus ~ .panel {
  display: block;
}
.show:focus ~ .hideButton {
  display: block;
}
.show:focus ~ .showButton {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="border:dotted 1px">
  Title 
  <a href="#" class="hide hideButton">hide</a>
  <a href="#" class="show showButton">show</a>
  <div class="panel" >
     <hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" /> 
      Something in here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Here ya go](http://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/zKGkwp)...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mar1/dy273yeu/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/ab08s7k6/

```css
#cont {
    display: none;
}
#show:target #cont {
    display: inline-block;
}
#show:target #show {
    display: none;
```

```html
<div id="show">
    <a href="#show" id="show">Open</a>
    <div id="cont">
        Something in here
        <a href="#hide" id="hide" >Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler than you think

http://jsfiddle.net/6W7XD/1/

HTML

```
<span class="span3" tabindex="0">Hide Me</span>
<span class="span2" tabindex="0">Show Me</span>
<p class="alert" >Some alarming information here</p>
```

CSS

```
body {
  display: block;
}
.span3:focus ~ .alert {
  display: none;
}
.span2:focus ~ .alert {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that is where I based my code off of. The part I am getting caught up on is that I want the 'Hide Me' to go away whenever it is clicked, and the 'Show Me' to appear. And then vice-versa when 'Show Me' is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible cause if you set `display: none;` to `hideButton` it won't be on `:focus` anymore.

in fact it works even without these:

```
.show:focus ~ .panel {
display: block;
}
.show:focus ~ .hideButton {
display: block;
}
.show:focus ~ .showButton {
display: none;
}
```

because as soon as you click on anything outside that `<a>`that hide won't be on `:focus` anymore which will lead to the show element to disappear anyway

tho you can set that hide with `position:absolute` and `top:-enoughpx` and it doesn't acttualy remove but it will disappear from the screen